# not display images in gridview as gallery

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I'm having images from url and it store in string array and on touch `ImageView` i'm trying to display images in `GridView` but images not displayed.

here is my `Activity` class.

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

private GridViewImageAdapter adapter;
private GridView gridView;
private int columnWidth;
ArrayList<String> imagepath;
Utility utils;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_view);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    imagepath = i.getExtras().getStringArrayList("event_photo");
    Log.i("Grid View", "hello..."+imagepath);
    utils = new Utility(this);

    // Initilizing Grid View
    InitilizeGridLayout();

    // Gridview adapter
    adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(GridViewActivity.this, imagepath,
            columnWidth);

    // setting grid view adapter
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void InitilizeGridLayout() {
    Resources r = getResources();
    float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            AppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());

    columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth() - ((AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

    gridView.setNumColumns(AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
    gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
    gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
    gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding,
            (int) padding);
    gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
    gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);
}

}
```

here is my adapter class.

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> _filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
private int imageWidth;

public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> filePaths,
        int imageWidth) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._filePaths = filePaths;
    this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._filePaths.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this._filePaths.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    // get screen dimensions
    Bitmap image = decodeFile(_filePaths.get(position), imageWidth,
            imageWidth);
    Log.i("Grid View", "image bitmap..."+image);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
            imageWidth));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    // image view click listener
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

    return imageView;
}

class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    int _postion;

    // constructor
    public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
        this._postion = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // on selecting grid view image
        // launch full screen activity
        /*Intent i = new Intent(_activity, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("position", _postion);
        _activity.startActivity(i);*/
    }

}

/*
 * Resizing image size
 */
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath, int WIDTH, int HIGHT) {
    try {

        File f = new File(filePath);

        Log.i("Grid View", "imagefb bfhdb"+filePath);
        Log.i("Grid View", "imagefb nj"+f);
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
        final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
            scale *= 2;

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

if any one have solution please let me know.